# Anyone able to configure a MULTI VM cluster on a single laptop?

Tags: centos, apache-zookeeper, cloudera-cdh

Has anyone been able to configure a 2 (or 3) node 3 CDH 4.1 cluster on 1 laptop.

The laptop is connected to the internet via WiFi and the VMs (VirtualBox, CentOS7) are configured to use bridged network. Each VM has a dedicated IP address and they can ping each other, they can ping the host, and they can connect to the internet.

I installed the software using these commands

```
systemctl disable firewalld.service
reboot
chmod 755 jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin
./jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/cloudera-cdh4.repo
cp cloudera-cdh4.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
rpm --import http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/RPMGPG-KEY-cloudera
yum install hadoop-hdfs-namenode
yum install hadoop-hdfs-journalnode
yum install zookeeper-server
yum install hadoop-hdfs-zkfc
service zookeeper-server init --myid=1
yum install zookeeper-server
service zookeeper-server start
```

you can see that I have disabled the firewall. However in the zookeeper.log I can see

```
2014-07-18 17:56:29,910 [myid:1] - WARN [WorkerSender[myid=1]:QuorumCnxManager@368] - Cannot open channel to 2 at election address nn2.abhishek.com/192.168.1.31:3888
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:354)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.toSend(QuorumCnxManager.java:327)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.process(FastLeaderElection.java:393)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.run(FastLeaderElection.java:365)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-07-18 17:56:29,911 [myid:1] - WARN [WorkerSender[myid=1]:QuorumCnxManager@368] - Cannot open channel to 3 at election address jt1.abhishek.com/192.168.1.32:3888
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:354)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.toSend(QuorumCnxManager.java:327)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.process(FastLeaderElection.java:393)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.run(FastLeaderElection.java:365)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Somehow I have a feeling that the CDH cannot be installed in this way and specially needs an enterprise setup where there is router and lan etc.

Has anyone been able to install CDH 4.1 on one laptop and 2 VMs? were you able to start zookeeper server?

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

I had to do the following on all the VMs.

```
systemctl disable firewalld.service
systemctl stop firewalld.service
```

I think on one of the machines the firewall was still running.

A good way to troubleshoot this problem is that from every machine you try to do this to all other machines

nc machine.domain.com 3888

if this is working then it means that traffic can flow. In my case, the ping was working but the nc was not.